# Why is an object wrapped to become a jQuery object?

Tags: jquery

In a JS module in a Rails app I found this bit of code:

```
$body.on('ajax:success', '.js-comment-create', function(data, xhr, status) {
  var content = $(xhr.content), 
      $comment = $(content.comment);
```

and I wonder why `xhr.content` needs to be or should be wrappend in `$()`?
I never paid attention to it as long as everything worked, but now, as I am debugging, I wonder why it is like this.

A quick test on the console shows that wrapping the xhr-Object return a JQuery object not a pure JS object. But what is the advantage of this in this particular situation where I just want to access data inside the object?

Edit: `xhr.content` is a JSON object, where the key `comment` holds a piece of html to replace some part of the DOM like so `$(".aside ul.messages").prepend($comment);`

Comment: You'll have to show what `xhr.content` looks like to get an answer to that question.

Comment: @JJJ updated the question

Comment: The answer must be in how $comment is used later on

Comment: @ Christophe Roussy: added that bit, too

Comment: *"`xhr.content` is a JSON object"* No, it's just an object. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: The code frankly looks like a bug. `$()` will return a jQuery object. jQuery object's don't have a (documented) `comment` property. Seems like it should just be `var $comment = $(xhr.content.comment);`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Quite possible that it is a bug. Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you've quoted and the information you've provided, the answer to "Why is an object wrapped to become a jQuery object?" is: It looks like a bug. Not only is there no good reason to do that, doing so will make the code not work correctly.

The code should almost certainly be just:

```
$body.on('ajax:success', '.js-comment-create', function(data, xhr, status) {
  var content = xhr.content, 
      $comment = $(content.comment);
```

or even

```
$body.on('ajax:success', '.js-comment-create', function(data, xhr, status) {
  var $comment = $(xhr.content.comment);
```

...unless something else uses `content` later.

Here's what happens when you do what the code does:

```js
var xhr = {
  content: {
    comment: "<p>I'm the comment</p>"
  }
};
var content = $(xhr.content),
    $comment = $(content.comment);
$comment.appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

vs. if you don't do the initial wrapping:

```js
var xhr = {
  content: {
    comment: "<p>I'm the comment</p>"
  }
};
var content = xhr.content,
    $comment = $(content.comment);
$comment.appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.